# group documents by array of objects

Tags: mongodb, aggregation

Documents example

```
{
  _id: 1,
  entity: 'Transaction',
  approvals: [
    {
      userId: 1, // ObjectID
      final: true,
      approved: false,
      date: ISODate('2021-01-01'),
    },
    {
      userId: 1,
      final: true,
      approved: false,
      date: ISODate('2021-02-01'),
    }
  ]
},
{
  _id: 2,
  entity: 'Transaction',
  approvals: [
    {
      userId: 1,
      final: true,
      approved: false,
      date: ISODate('2021-01-01'),
    },
    {
      userId: 1,
      final: true,
      approved: false,
      date: ISODate('2021-02-01'),
    }
  ]
},
{
  _id: 3,
  entity: 'Transaction',
  approvals: [
    {
      userId: 1,
      final: true,
      approved: true,
      date: ISODate('2021-01-01'),
    },
    {
      userId: 2,
      final: true,
      approved: false,
      date: ISODate('2021-02-01'),
    }
  ]
},
{
  _id: 4,
  entity: 'Transaction',
  approvals: [
    {
      userId: 1,
      final: true,
      approved: true,
      date: ISODate('2021-01-01'),
    },
    {
      userId: 2,
      final: true,
      approved: false,
      date: ISODate('2021-02-01'),
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to group such documents on the following criteria:

- entity
- approvals.approved
- approvals.userId
- approvals.final
- approvals.date

approvals array can contain multiple values, probably unsorted, where as I need to sort them by date; in case number of approvals is different - two objects belong to different groups.
Is that possible to do with use of Mongodb 4.2 facilities and what the most efficient way would be? I was thinking about a hash generation but not sure MongoDB has such function.

Desired result:

```
{
  ids: [1, 2],
  entity: 'Transaction',
  approvals: [
    {
      userId: 1,
      final: true,
      approved: false,
      date: ISODate('2021-01-01'),
    },
    {
      userId: 1,
      final: true,
      approved: false,
      date: ISODate('2021-02-01'),
    }
  ]
}
{
  ids: [3, 4],
  entity: 'Transaction',
  approvals: [
    {
      userId: 1,
      final: true,
      approved: true,
      date: ISODate('2021-01-01'),
    },
    {
      userId: 2,
      final: true,
      approved: false,
      date: ISODate('2021-02-01'),
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
 mongos> db.h.aggregate([      { $unwind:"$approvals"}   , {$group:{ _id:{ ent:"$entity" , app:"$approvals.approved" , fin:"$approvals.final" ,dat:"$approvals.date"  } ,count:{$sum:1}    }} , {$sort:{dat:1}}  ])
 { "_id" : { "ent" : "Transaction", "app" : true, "fin" : true, "dat" : ISODate("2021-02-01T19:35:37.883Z") }, "count" : 1 }
 { "_id" : { "ent" : "Transaction", "app" : true, "fin" : true, "dat" : ISODate("2021-02-01T19:41:37.931Z") }, "count" : 1 }
```

Comment: unfortunately this won't work, I've just tested this and with 2 documents in a collection I have in result after such aggregation 3 documents; obviously number of groups can't be more than documents I want to group

Comment: maybe you need different criteria , please, provide the desired output ?

Comment: provided data and and desired result